# sharepoint 2013 user profile two active directory connections

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-userprofile

I am trying to add another AD synchronization connection to the already exisitng one. I see in FIM that the users and groups have come in and am also able to add a group to an audience from the new domain, but the new domain users are not getting propagated to the Site Collections. I am a developer rather than an administrator and not really sure where to look? Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can create one, two or multiple sync connections per UPA.  However, you should only have a single sync connection per Active Directory forest.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I don't know what a sync connection is but I have a lead at least now. Do you think the sync connection would affect the propagation of the user profiles to the site collections?

Comment: I have already configured the Sync Connection and got the users coming into SharePoint. I can see them in the user profile but not in site collection users. I cannot add them in permissions. I'm wondering if I need to do anything more to get the new users into site collections.